# How does Datasheet View Calculate width?

Tags: 2010, master-page, css, custom-masterpage, datasheet

I have SharePoint 2010, I have created a custom master page, and everything works except for the datasheet view. The problem I have is the scrollbar on the datasheet view goes passed the end of the datasheet window. If I resize the browser window, it readjusts and is correct. But when I maximize again, it goes outside the screen again.

How does SharePoint calculate the datasheet view? as its ActiveX, I can't mess around with the datasheet CSS in real time.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? That would help immensely to narrow down the CSS class/id responsible for the hickup.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I outlined my fix here:

https://sppro-public.sharepoint.com/Blog/Post/13/Vertical-scrollbar-overflows-out-of-div-when-fixed-with-used

its a bit of hack, there must be a better solution. But basically I overrided the onresize event